# Nothing recognised using SwiftOCR

Tags: swift, ocr, swiftocr

I am trying to recognise numbers in a Sudoku board. I'm using a sample printed in Times new Roman, and I have trained the system using that font, and limited the characters to numbers by setting recognizableCharacters = "0123456789
testImages.zip

For my sample set of test images, which are all about 177 x 184 pixels, the only number that is ever recognised is '1'. Everything else is unrecognised.

I have converted all of the images to black & white only to increase contrast, but I was getting the same result with natural colours.

Here are some of the images I'm trying to recognise

[image: sample image - 4]

[image: sample image - 2]

I know that there will be suggestions that I should use Tesseract - but I'm trying to get this one working as it *should* be faster.

There must be something simple that I'm missing...

Comment: "SwiftOCR is optimized for recognizing short, one line long alphanumeric codes..." - One line only. VIA https://github.com/garnele007/SwiftOCR/blob/master/README.md#swiftocr

Comment: The images I'm working with are one character only.  I'm finding edges and parsing the sudoku board to generate 81 individual images which I then try to identify.  But thanks for the link to the original source, which is - of course - where I started

Comment: If you want, you can get the Tesseract and train it for your data/font but I am afraid it might take a while..

Comment: If you are still interested try this library that I wrote, it uses Tesseract but it is quite fast: https://github.com/robertoferraz/OCRSlicer